A package installed successfully in root environment but not in other environments with Anaconda
I need to install a specific package from the scientific society. The author mentioned that the Visual Stuido needs to be installed for the package to run. I installed Visual Studio and i am indeed able to install the package with 'pip install'. However, when I created a new visual environment and tried installing the same package under this environment, it failed to build the wheel of that package. I got the following error.
Building wheels for collected packages: BabelViscoFDTD
  Building wheel for BabelViscoFDTD (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1

I then uninstalled Visual Studio. After that, I found that the package cannot be installed under the root environment any more. The the error message I got was the same as above. I reinstalled Visual Studio. As expected, the pakcage can be installed successfully under the root environment, but sitll not under other visual environment.
I was thinking that there must be some necessary dependencies from Visual Stuido that are necessary for installing the package, but I have no idea how to get that work in an environment other than the root. By the way, for some other reasons that I need to install the pakcage for a specific environment but not for the root.
Could anyone help me what cuased this problem and what I should do. Thanks.

It seems like there is a problem with this specific package? Is it possible to get more info from the author?
